# show binary photo with flask and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i have a encode binary picture in database , i want to show the photo with flask . So i need to decode and after that, show it in the browser. I dont want to use html file, i know that i can do it without html.

I have this code , but it is only from directory , i dont know how decode the data and show

```
PATH_FILES = getcwd() + "/files/"


@images.route("/file/<string:name_file>")
def get_image(name_file):
       return send_from_directory(PATH_FILES, path=name_file, as_attachment=False)
```

imagine that already have de encodeData:

```
encodeimage=b'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'
```

so how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

its a base64 encoded image, you can use it as in below example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Display base64 Image</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, 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' />
  </body>
</html>
```

if you save the above file as html and open it with a browser, you will see the actual image.